# Object to array in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need help with this code.

I working with `"@angular/cli": "~12.0.5"`.

The `createArray` method receives an object and I want to transform the object to an array, but I have an error in 'userObj [key]'. I get the object (**userObj**) from Firebase through an http request and I can't change its structure.

This is the error message. -> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'

Thanks!

```
const userObj = {

   'SJKLDFAD903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 1'
   },
   'PLMKL-BAD89':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 2'
   },
   'JHK34R-R903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 3'
   }
}

export class UserModel{
   id: string;
   name: string;
}

private createArray(userObj){ /*(userObj: object)*/
    const users: UserModel[] = [];

    if (userObj == null) { return []; }

    Object.keys(userObj).forEach(key => {
      
       const user: UserModel = userObj[key];
       user.id = key;

       users.push(user);
    });

    return users;
}
```

Comment: What is the formate of your output array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
private createArray(userObj){ /*(userObj: object)*/
    const users: UserModel[] = [];

    if (userObj == null) { return []; }

    for (const [key, object] of Object.entries(userObj)) {
        const user: UserModel = object as UserModel;
        user.id = key;
        users.push(user);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Comment: Hi @N.F, your code working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yow broh.

use `Object.values` instead

```js
const userObj = {

   'SJKLDFAD903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 1'
   },
   'PLMKL-BAD89':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 2'
   },
   'JHK34R-R903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 3'
   }
}

export class UserModel{
   id: string;
   name: string;
}

private createArray(userObj): UserModel[] {
    return Object.values(userObj)
}



const userObj = {

   'SJKLDFAD903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 1'
   },
   'PLMKL-BAD89':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 2'
   },
   'JHK34R-R903':{
      id: '',
      name: 'User 3'
   }
}

function createArray(userObj) {
    return Object.values(userObj)
}

console.log(createArray(userObj))
```

Comment: Hi @Ernesto thanks for sharing your code, but in each iteration the '' id '' must take the value for example of '' SJKLDFAD903 ".